# how to pull docker network configuration and containers

Tags: docker

In the Docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/) they set up a custom bridge network with the containers connected, like so

`$ docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network`

`$ docker run -d --network=my-bridge-network --name db training/postgres`

`$ docker run -d --network=my-bridge-network --name web training/webapp python app.py`

These two docker containers spin up and connect to the same network.

But I can not find a way to save this configuration like you would commit a docker image, so that I could pull the network configuration and it would pull the containers ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the bridge is done on setting up the docker network when calling `docker network create ...` and configuring docker container network mode is done when calling `docker run --network=...`.

You cannot store the information in docker image that when it starts it should be connected to bridge X, this is not run-time configurable and outside docker image's scope when running inside a docker container.

You could either bash script the `docker network` & `docker run`commands or use docker-compose `.yml` file to script the configuration each container needs to be run against, e.g.:

```
version: "2"

services:
    my-app
     build: .
     image: my-app-image
     container_name: my_app_container
     ports:
       - 3000:3000
     networks:
       - my-network

networks:
   my-network:
    external: true
```